# Send data from .NET application to Rails application

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, database, listener

How can I send data from a Windows .NET application to a Rails application? The .NET application continously collects data from some workstations and periodically needs to send the data to a database. I will like to have the Rails application authenticate the sending .NET application and parse the receiving data before storing it in a SQLite database. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [web service](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/Web_Services.html) in Rails and call it using .NET.

Info on creating a web service in Rails at this previous question: [how to create a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993900/how-to-create-a-web-service)

Calling a web service in .NET is easily Googlable (but here's a good place to start: [Consuming REST based web services in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727649/consuming-rest-based-web-services-in-net)).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a web service.  [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979980/start-using-ruby-on-rails-web-services-and-oauth) does a good job of explaining it